# root to subdomain in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns, subdomain

I have the website www.Meer.li and I want to change the root url, so people get into www.iphone.meer.li when they enter the website name. How do I manage this?

I have some code already, but it doesn't work:

```
root :to => 'designs#featured', :subdomain => "iphone"
```

Comment: Does this [Railscast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3) help? The examples given are quite useful.

Comment: I've already seen it and it's a very cool screencast. I can't get the subdomain to work as I want it to though. I'm mystified over why it doesn't point to the subdomain, when I tell it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this works but I'm not sure how much of a correct way of doing it it is...

```
match "/" => redirect(:subdomain => "iphone")
```

Comment: I ended up doing this: "match '(*any)' => redirect(:to => 'designs#featured', :subdomain => "iphone"), :constraints => { :subdomain => "" }". What do you say to that solution?

Comment: Yes actually you probably would need to use constraints so that the redirect doesn't happen when under that subdomain :)